# Hadoop FileUtils not able to write files on local(Unix) filesystem from Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to write file to local `FileSystem` using FileSystem library of `org.apache.hadoop.fs`. Below is my one liner code inside the big scala code that should be doing this, but it's not.

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(false, hdfsSourcePath, new Path(newFile.getAbsolutePath), true)
```

The value of `newFile` is:

```
val newFile = new File(s"${localPath}/fileName.dat")
```

`localPath` is just a variable containing the full path on local disk.
`hdfsSourcePath` is the full path on HDFS location.

The job executes properly but I don't see the files created on local. I'm running it through `Spark` engine in `cluster` mode, that's why I used the `copyToLocalFile` method which overloads the 4th argument of `useRawLocalFileSystem` and set it to `true`. Using this, we can avoid getting the files being written on the executor node.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used the copyToLocalFile method which overloads the 4th argument of useRawLocalFileSystem and set it to true. Using this, we can avoid getting the files being written on the executor node.

I think you got this point wrong. Cluster mode makes driver run on executor node and local file system is that executor's file system. `useRawLocalFileSystem` only prevents writing checksum files (->[info](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjYrMbZ0cviAhUi-yoKHR7MCBkQ7gEwAXoECAgQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftranslate.google.com%2Ftranslate%3Fhl%3Dpl%26sl%3Den%26u%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.pl%2Fbooks%253Fid%253DbKPEwR-Pt6EC%2526pg%253DPA77%2526lpg%253DPA77%2526dq%253Dhadoop%252Blocal%252Bfilesystem%252Bchecksumed%252Bor%252Braw%2526source%253Dbl%2526ots%253DkRbF3ve8Fl%2526sig%253DACfU3U1SvTuIuE4iP4xBr8rQRnmqmBdc9A%26prev%3Dsearch&usg=AOvVaw39dt-qhcajydaGq5d-w85C)), it does not make the files appear on machine that is submitting the job, which is probably what you expected.

The best you can do is to save files to HDFS and retrieve them explicitly after the job finishes.

Comment: I certainly got this point wrong then. It's simply irrelevant then the mere presence of these copyToLocal methods in the utility. Just a query, will `copyMerge` do the necessary job?

Comment: It won't. Driver simply doesn't have any connection with the node that is submitting the job. It's like "fire and forget". But what you can also try is using client mode if that's possible in your case.

Comment: Using client mode isn't possible, I can only execute the job in `cluster` mode only. Not sure using `HDFS` commands inside the program is how much feasible for copying the files after program finishes; have to try.

Comment: Hi. I was trying to follow your suggestion on moving the files it has been created via Hadoop specific commands. Fell into a permission issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420928/executing-hdfs-commands-from-inside-scala-script