# Executing hdfs commands from inside scala script

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to execute a `HDFS` specific command from inside the scala script being executed by Spark in cluster mode. Below the command:

```
val cmd = Seq("hdfs","dfs","-copyToLocal","/tmp/file.dat","/path/to/local")
val result = cmd.!!
```

The job fails at this stage with the error as below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/2087791-yarn-NODEMANAGER/log4j.properties (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:557)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

However, when I run the same command separately in Spark shell, it executes just fine and the file is copied as well.

```
scala> val cmd = Seq("hdfs","dfs","-copyToLocal","/tmp/file_landing_area/file.dat","/tmp/local_file_area")
cmd: Seq[String] = List(hdfs, dfs, -copyToLocal, /tmp/file_landing_area/file.dat, /tmp/local_file_area)

scala> val result = cmd.!!
result: String = ""
```

I don't understand the permission denied error. Although it displays as a `FileNotFoundException`. Totally confusing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is not the best exception to throw, but it is sort of understandable - it couldn't find a file with the path you specified (that it could open). Do you have read permissions on that file (and read on any parent directories)? Does getting read permissions on the file solve your problem.?

Comment: Yes, file has read permissions; owned by the same user I'm executing the job. I can only suspect it's the spark executor which might be running with a different executor might not be having read permission. But that's just a hard guess. 

Edited Part: I can't provide read permissions as the directory gets created during the program execution itself.

Comment: @GMc, I did give the folder full permission this time during the execution of the code, same error.

Comment: For  google-readers, to use `cmd.!!`  you must call **`import sys.process._` before**.

Answer (score 0):

As per error, it is checking hdfs data into var folder which I suspect configuration issue or it is not pointing to correct one. 
Using seq and executing HDFS command is not good practise. It is useful only for spark shell. Using same approach in code not advisable. Instead of this try to use below Scala File system API to move data From  or To HDFS.  Please check below sample code just for reference that might help you.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val conf = new Configuration()

val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)

val hdfspath = new Path("hdfs:///user/nikhil/test.csv")
val localpath = new Path("file:///home/cloudera/test/")

fs.copyToLocalFile(hdfspath,localpath)
```

Please use below link for more reference regarding Scala File system API.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile(boolean,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: Thanks Nikk, is that working for you? I even tried hardcoding but couldn't get it to transfer.

Comment: I think you ran on local mode, if through Spark. While in cluster mode, this isn't gonna put the file on local driver node.

Comment: Yes, I have run this code in client mode. But it will also work in Cluster mode and write data to the local system of node where Spark driver is running. 
If you want to write at particular node then you can use local file system path with that IP address of that node. That will write data if spark has write permission for that node.

Comment: I think, somehow your Yarn log file's (log4j) permission has been changed. Check and try to Give permission to all for below files and run it again                   
/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/2087791-yarn-NODEMANAGER/log4j.properties

Comment: Thanks Nikk, but the log4j works for every other job, just gives issue in this job only; it's not the log4j configs, but the code that I'm running. copyToLocalFile utility, for me isn't doing the job properly. Right now, even the job doesn't fail, it finishes successfully. I try to include print messages to track the flow, all seems perfect. No exception thrown, just the file doesn't gets written.

Comment: Are you checking Local FS of driver node ? Since you have run job in cluster mode, there might be possibility that you are checking at different node not on driver node. Could you please check driver node for the job that you had run and login to that node (driver) and check local FS. You will get file there if there was no issue in written. Correct me if I am wrong.